# how to check in database for new row insert or not in iphone and simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend please help some one i want to see in my data base in table were my new row was add or not how can i see that

please some one give me demo code or chek my code in proper what my mistak

here my appdeleget class method

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDB {
    NSString* databaseName = @"demo.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.sqlite"];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success) return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}


-(void)insertData{

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database); NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO User (uname,id,password,message) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",Gmessage,1 ,Glocation,Gjourney];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [Gjourney UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [Glocation UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [Gmessage UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if (SQLITE_DONE !=sqlite3_step(statement)) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Record" message:@"Contact Added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;

        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"record" message:@"record not created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;
        }   

        sqlite3_reset(statement);

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);    

}
```

Here is my controller class button code

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{

    Gjourney=mTextJourney.text;
    Glocation=mTextLocation.text;
    Gmessage=mDescription.text;
    AddListAppDelegate *appDelegate =(AddListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate insertData];
}
```

Comment: In future please take the time to format the code in your question appropriately (using the "{}" editor control).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) function to check if the row was added or not, as long as you're not accessing the database from multiple threads, etc.

Comment: i am creat table which is nil and i am insert the value from button action how can i insert all record in table help